# Block users from accessing my cron job script

Tags: php, cron

I have a cron job script in a php file, named `cron.php` , which runs after every 3 hours. As it is kept in the public html folder, any user can access it. But I don't want that. I'm searching for a process by which I can ensure that, only my server can access that file and run that script. No user will be able to access that file.

To do that, what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to store the file outside of the webroot.

Another option is to pass in an extra parameter when you run the script via cron, and check that this parameter is present (which it won't be when it's accessed by web request).  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php for examples of working with command line arguments in PHP

Comment: Does "outside of the webroot" means outside of public_html folder? Would you give an example where to put cron scripts?

Comment: Exactly, put it outside of the public_html folder. Where it should go depends a bit on your setup but even one directory up (so at the same level as public_html) should stop web access.